# Add trailing slash at the end of URL

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm using .NET Core 2.1. I'm trying to permanent redirect any non-file URLs (does not contain a dot) without an ending slash to a corresponding URL with the ending slash. Is there a way to accomplish this using rewriteOptions?

```
        var rewriteOptions = new RewriteOptions()
            .AddRedirect("^[^.]*$", "$1", 301)
            .AddRedirectToHttpsPermanent();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern should match :

```
/js                           # has no preceding segements
/www/js                       # has a segment  
/www/test.d/js                # contains a dot within preceding segments
```

and should not match :

```
/www/js/jquery.js             # contains a dot at last segment
/www/js/                      # has a trailing slash
/www/js/hello.d/jquery.js/    # has a trailing slash
```

So create such a pattern as below :

```
var pattern = @"^(((.*/)|(/?))[^/.]+(?!/$))$"; 

var options = new RewriteOptions()
    .AddRedirect(pattern, "$1/",301);
```

and it will work .

#### Test cases :

should redirect :

```
GET https://localhost:5001/js HTTP/1.1
GET https://localhost:5001/xx/js HTTP/1.1
GET https://localhost:5001/xx/test.d/js HTTP/1.1
```

should not redirect :

```
GET https://localhost:5001/xx/js/ HTTP/1.1
GET https://localhost:5001/xx/jquery.js HTTP/1.1
GET https://localhost:5001/xx/hello.d/jquery.js HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: Anti pattern IMO, unless he's serving static files via an Action method

Comment: @Marcel why so?

Comment: @lolol With ASP.NET Core you can configure the request pipeline very easily. That's the Configure() method in Startup.cs. It is a pipeline meaning it will execute in the order it is implemented. So i'm saying if you add the redirect as the last thing in the pipeline (so at the bottom in Configure()) it will be the last thing executed. Then it won't affect the static files. Because static files are handled higher up in the pipeline. No need to add complex regex while you can just re-order the pipeline to handle static files first

Comment: @Marcel I'm serving the static files in the same way as yours . What makes the different is the regex pattern and the 301 status code .

Comment: @Marcel I understand why you are saying it as "Anti Pattern" . But I didn't use the redirect middleware with staticfiles in a wrong order. Those urls  are just used to test whether the pattern works . Actually, I add a `/xx` segment within almost every test case to avoid any affects by `staticFiles` .

Comment: Ah i see now the confusion. I actually created a file named jquery.js and placed it in xx/hello.d/jquery.js. Then my code works. That's what i'm assuming OP has. If you just test the URL's without an actual file. Then no, my code will not work

Comment: So something like this:
`app.UseHttpsRedirection();` `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/errors/{0}");`
`app.UseResponseCompression();`
`app.UseStaticFiles();`
`app.UseRewriter(rewriteOptions);`
`app.UseMvc();`
?

Answer (score 5):

According to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#regex-examples) to add a trailing slash it's:

```
var options = new RewriteOptions()
        .AddRedirect("(.*[^/])$", "$1/")
        .AddRedirectToHttpsPermanent();
```

To prevent it happening to  static files, make sure `app.UseStaticFiles();` is called **before** `app.UseRewriter(options);`

so:

```
// Return static files and end the pipeline.
app.UseStaticFiles(); // <--- **before** the redirect

var options = new RewriteOptions()
    .AddRedirect("(.*[^/])$", "$1/")
    .AddRedirectToHttpsPermanent();
app.UseRewriter(options);
```

Calling UseStaticFiles() first will short-cut the pipeline for static files. So no redirects are done on the static files.

More info on Startup.Configure order here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#order

Comment: That seems not correct . The pattern will also match /xx/hello.d/jquery.js , and then redirect it

Comment: Can not reproduce. I've tested the code with the file path given. It works fine on my end. Only way it does not work if you place UseStaticeFiles() underneath. 
You will need to provide more details, maybe your whole configure() method in startup. And also maybe your wwwroot structure

Comment: For what? My code works, so does yours. Maybe you have caching while testing mine? @itminus

Comment: I mean the redirect rule you configured via regex, will also match ` /xx/hello.d/jquery.js` and the redirect it to` /xx/hello.d/jquery.js/` . You could find that if you checkout the log information . It is not redirected by other middlewares , but by the redirect middleware itself  .

Comment: @itminus I only get the redirect on jquery.js if i place UseStaticFile() underneath the redirect. Then yes. That is my point. It should work just by reordering the methods - other then that i don't know why it's not working for you

Comment: Actually , it does works in some way . What I am saying is that the regex pattern you configured above , will also match `/xx/hello.d/jquery.js` and then redirect it . It will works because static files will not care about the trailing slash and treat `/xx/hello.d/jquery.js/` as a file , instead of a directory .

Answer (score 1):

Way for adding trailing slash for non file URL's is by configuring the middleware in startup.cs after app.UseStaticFiles();

```
public class TrailingSlashUrlMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public TrailingSlashUrlMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            string currentPath = httpContext.Request.Path;

            if (currentPath != "/")
            {
                

                string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(currentPath);

                bool NeedRedirection = false;

                var currentQueryString = httpContext.Request.QueryString;

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ext))
                {
                    if (!currentPath.EndsWith("/"))
                    {
                        currentPath = currentPath + "/";
                        NeedRedirection = true;
                    }

                    //if (currentQueryString.HasValue)
                    //{
                    //    string queryString = currentQueryString.Value;

                    //    if (!queryString.EndsWith("/"))
                    //    {
                    //        queryString = queryString + "/";
                    //        NeedRedirection = true;
                    //    }

                    //    currentPath += queryString;
                    //}
                }
                if (NeedRedirection)
                {
                    httpContext.Response.Redirect(currentPath, true);
                    return;
                }
            }

            await _next(httpContext);
        }
    }
```

if you need to apply this to query string uncomment the commented code.